# Javascript code is drawing the same image even when image path changes

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

The problem I am currently having is that if I try and draw 2 different images, it draws the same image twice. All of this code is happening within a loop (could this be a problem?). The code calling the images to be drawn is:

```
    drawImage(imageData.background, 0, 0, 2048, 1918, 0, 0, 2048, 1918);
    drawImage(currentData.player.image, 0, 0, 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 32);
```

and my drawImage function is as follows:

```
    function drawImage(whatIMG, spriteX, spriteY, sizeX, sizeY, posX, posY, x, y) {
        drawCanvasImage = new Image();
        drawCanvasImage.src = whatIMG;
        drawCanvasImage.onload = function(){
          ctx.drawImage(drawCanvasImage, spriteX, spriteY, sizeX, sizeY, posX, posY, x, y);
        }
    };
```

So although imageData.background and currentData.player.image are completely different, only the last image link mentioned will be the image that is drawn on the canvas. [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMoxs.png)

My gut feeling is telling me I may need to somehow clear the 'drawCanvasImage' object after it has loaded the image, although I am not sure as it should be deleted after the function finishes every time (?).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: `imageData.background` and `currentData.player.image` are both path to images ? It may not help, but I think that with this code, you're downloading the `img` each time you want to draw it. Perhaps it would be better to have a `SpriteManager` that would download the images once, and store them somewhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, both 'imageData.background' and 'currentData.player.image' are paths to images. You are correct, I will be looking to implement a feature that downloads all images on load and then never download on every loop. Going back to the previous point, if I comment out the second drawImage function, the first drawImage correctly draws the image I want to display. This shows the links are working correctly.

Comment: I think I understood the problem, could you try adding `var` keyword in front of the line `drawCanvasImage = new Image();` ?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help. I played around with your code, and in the end all it took was adding `(drawCanvasImage)` to the end of my drawImage function. No idea why, but it works so that counts doesn't it... DOESN'T it?! Anyway, thanks so much :)

Comment: Check my answer that gives the explanation, and another way to solve your problem (i think), javascript is a complex language, and I think it's important to understand how those things works, otherwise you may struggle again on the same problems : async is difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, when you don't use the word `var` to declare your variable, your variable is implicitely global.

When you do

```
function drawImage(whatIMG, spriteX, spriteY, sizeX, sizeY, posX, posY, x, y) {
    drawCanvasImage = new Image();
    drawCanvasImage.src = whatIMG;
    ...
}
```

the function will be executed on the same `drawCanvasImage`. And especially, if you call this function twice in a row, the `drawCanvasImage` will be changed really fast, before the `onload` function can be called. The result of the execution will look like this :

```
drawCanvasImage = new Image();
drawCanvasImage.src = imageData.background;

drawCanvasImage = new Image();
drawCanvasImage.src = currentData.player.image;

// After the thing is loaded
ctx.drawImage(drawCanvasImage, ...); // params the first call... maybe
ctx.drawImage(drawCanvasImage, ...); // params of the other one
```

Maybe writing your function like this will solve your problem :

```
function drawImage(whatIMG, spriteX, spriteY, sizeX, sizeY, posX, posY, x, y) {
    // use var keyword so drawCanvasImage is scoped in this function
    // when you will call this function again,
    // a different drawCanvasImage will be used
    var drawCanvasImage = new Image(); 
    drawCanvasImage.src = whatIMG;
    drawCanvasImage.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(drawCanvasImage, spriteX, spriteY, sizeX, sizeY, posX, posY, x, y);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks, I fiddled the code around a bit and now it works. thanks for adding it to an official, answer, now i can give you more points or something! and that is interesting about how the lack of a var makes something global... I didn't know that! :)